# Why is this returning two values? Easy python beginner

Tags: python, function, class, methods

Can someone please explain why my enter method in the following class is returning two values? I'm learning python and in the process of creating a simple game to grasp OOP and classes. Anyhow I need the enter method to return a random snippet from the snippets list. But I keep getting two snippets instead of one. Can someone explain why?

```
    from sys import exit
    from random import randint




  class Island(object):

    def enter(self):
     pass



  class Loser(Island):
    snippets = ["Welcome to loser Island",
            "Can't win them all", 
            "There's always next time"]             
   def enter(self): 
      print Loser.snippets[randint(0,len(self.snippets)-1)]



  loser_test = Loser()
  loser_test.enter()
```

Comment: Is this your full code? As it is in this code, Loser.enter doesn't return anything; it just prints something. 

Also, could you please fix the indentation to reflect the class structure?

Comment: Did you used `print loser_test.enter()`?

Comment: @Kasra They shouldn't have to. There is a `print` statement in the method itself

Comment: it returns no values .... so I dont believe you that it returns two ...

Comment: @Cyber  As OP says *I keep getting two snippets* i think he had does that!

Comment: The above code only prints one thing for me, so the problem must not lie there.

Comment: ditto that it prints just one.  did you by any chance have some colons in your original code?  snippets[1] will get one item,  Cant Win.   but snippets[1:] would return a list slice : Cant Win, Theres Always.

Comment: tritto.  random.randint(0,3) is always a single number, and snippets[int] always returns one of those strings for me

Comment: I added the beginning of my code. I still get two "snippets" to return..

Comment: as some have pointed out, it is hard to tell if you call enter twice or if enter really prints 2 values.  why dont you change it to _return_ a Loser.snippets[<randint>] instead and see if you still have the problem?  you can do print (loser_test.enter())

Comment: Yes, that's it. Changing from print to return fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you'll create a class and then describe the behavior and contents of an instance of that class. An instance of a class is an object whose type is that class. For example, `john = Person('John', 'Doe')` would create a `Person` object, sending `'John'` and `'Doe'` to the object's `__init__` method (a constructor).

The following sticks to instances of a class by making use of the word `self`. `self` is not a keyword (like `in`); it's just the word that an object's description uses to refer to the object itself. You can use any word (like `xyz` in `for xyz in [1,2,3]`), but `self` is preferred.

```
>>> import random
>>> class L(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.snippets = ["Welcome", "Can't", "There's"]
...     def enter(self):
...             print (random.choice(self.snippets))
...
>>> l = L()
>>> l.enter()
There's
>>> l.enter()
There's
>>> l.enter()
Welcome
>>> l.enter()
Can't
>>>
```

Comment: this really isnt much different than Cyber's answer... Its worth an upvote, but i dont really think either of them actually solves OP's issue (which granted OP did not provide enough information to actually solve)

Comment: I figured I would provide a bit more explanation of classes, as well as lay out the usual structure for a class (notably, defining an `__init__()` that assigns `self` variables). Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)

```
def enter(self): 
    print random.choice(self.snippets)
```

Comment: How does this answer the user's questions? It's a good style choice, yes, but beyond that...

Comment: Because rather than trying to solve an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), if they are after selecting a random item from their list, I'm proposing an alternative to their obfuscated random list indexing method

Comment: I haven't voted anywhere in this question, but keep in mind that an "upvote for no reason" brigade is [no better than](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253383/upvotes-that-cancel-out-downvotes) a "downvote for no reason" brigade.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to take a guess and say its because you have something like this

```
class Island:
    def __init__(self):
        print self.enter()
```

but its really a stab in the dark ... since you have not provided enough information to actually answer your question. ... (really I guess this question should be closed until OP provides sufficient datas)

you can test this by just running

```
loser_test = Loser()
```

and if you see a print that is almost definately your problem